# Scroll most recently selected object in jquery toggle to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

After toggling open several sections and I have a heading near the bottom of the window, if I click it, it opens, but the content is outside of the view. I would like the heading to scroll to the top so that the content can be seen. I've been trying scrollTo and scrollIntoView, but have not had any luck yet.

The toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".toggle_container").hide(); 
    $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

The content

```
<h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Link Name</a></h2> 
<div class="toggle_container"> 
    <div class="block"> 
    <h3>Need a Website?</h3> 
    <p>Consequat te olim letalis</p> 
        </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="#">Link Name</a>` causes the page to scroll to the top. This is not the correct method for creating a "null" link. Use: `<a href="javascript://">Link Name</a>`. Why you're putting the click event on the H2 and not on the A is baffling as well.

Here's help with your scroll action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".toggle_container").hide();
    $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
        window.scrollTo($(this).position().left,$(this).position().top)
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on creating "null" link, have always just done it with #. The click event on the H2 was just the way it was from the tutorial I had found, just trying to get the functionality working before changing what they had done. Your suggestion appears to be working, almost, when I toggle open a section it doesn't work, and when I toggle close a section it rises up and then closes, like I want it to.